# Polynomial approximation in L^p norms

Tags: approximation-theory

Hello,

I am very new to the field of approximation theory, and since
an extended search on the Internet did not provide answers for 
two rather basic questions, I decided to ask them here.

1) From my understanding upper bounds for

$$ \inf_{q} \int_{-1}^{1} |f(x) - q(x)|^{2p} dt $$

with $f$ continuous and $q$ a polynomial of degree $n$, are expressed
in terms of the $L^p$ smoothness of $f$ and in terms of the degree $n$. 
Could somebody point me to a proof
of such a result?

2) Heuristically, what kind of information do lower bounds for the
above infinum contain ? (For example, suppose that I can
give a lower bound of $p!$ for the above infinimum as $p \rightarrow \infty$).

My last question might not be well-posed, so if it doesn't make sense please ignore
it.

Thank you.

Comment: It is unfortunate that you let $p$ denote both a polynomial and a positive integer. I guess that it is clear that you take the infimum over polynomials, of a certain degree? But this should be clarified.

Comment: Can you clarify 2) please? Wouldn't it make more sense to study lower bounds as $n\to\infty$ when $f$ is taken to be the worst one from some function space?

Answer (score 3):

A good introductory lookup for 1) (and similar problems) is the book "Spectral Methods: Fundamentals in Single Domains" by Canuto, Hussaini, Quarteroni & Zang.  Chapter 5, in particular.  Equation (5.4.16)  gives a bound for the $L^p$ norm approximation problem in terms of the L^p smoothness of $f$ and its derivatives:
$$
\inf_{q \in \mathbb{P}_n} \| f - q \| _{L^p} \leq C N^{-m} \left ( \sum^{m} _{k=\min(m,n+1)} \| f^{(k)} \|^p _{L^p} \right )^{\frac{1}{p}}
$$
According to the bibliographical notes section (p.291) a proof can be found in this [paper](http://www.springerlink.com/content/42m3284x30mv5307/).

Comment: There's a small typo here: the $n$'s should be either all capital or not as they all refer to the polynomial degree.

Comment: The link has gone dead.

Answer (score 1):

Results on the $L^p$-approximation theory can be found in the basic books on the subject:

Timan, A.F. Theory of approximation of functions of a real variable. Oxford: Pergamon Press. 1963.

Achieser, N.I. Theory of approximation. New York: Frederick Ungar Publishing Co. (1956).